# C++20 not available

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, g++, c++20

I'm currently trying to build code using gcc / g++ like this:

```
g++-10 -std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra -c -o hw01.o hw01.cpp
```

(Also the same outcome with gcc-10, gcc, g++)
And I have a static check in my Code:

```
static_assert(__cplusplus >= 202002L);
```

which sadly fails every time. As far as I've reserched, the used C++ version depends on gcc and it's version. gcc-10 has version 10.3.0 and the normal gcc command uses version 9.4.0, so both should be able to use C++20 as specified in the build command.
Yet when looking in VsCode, the variable `__cplusplus` evaluates to `201402L`, therefore making the assertion fail.

Even when uninstalling / reinstalling the compilers (or sudo apt remove cpp) this problem persists.

Any help? How do I get my system to use a newer C++ version?

PS: I'm working on a Ubuntu WSL (host system is Windows 10)

Edit: Since most recommondations are to neglect the static test and f.e. test for a different value of __cplusplus or simply throw out the test, i'm doing this for a university assignment. The satic test is non-negotiable, can not be changed and also not altered. I have to make the test pass by changing the build value of my local C++ version, I just don't know how.

Comment: If you're using g++ 10.3 (or later) trying to use `-std=c++20` (actually, Godbolt only shows it switching to `202002` in 11.1)

Comment: -std=c++20 has the same effect: None

Comment: Checked https://godbolt.org/z/4WGszPsdM 10.3 should support C++20

Comment: It should be up to your build system to enforce which standard of C++ to use, not your code.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04, the most recent LTS version, also has `g++-11` and `g++-12` both which do C++20.  So if you have an older Ubuntu, consider upgrading.

Comment: @PepijnKramer It supports C++20, but [does not set __cplusplus correctly](https://godbolt.org/z/9dYG7sE3v)

Comment: @PepijnKramer this doesn't change the facth that `__cplusplus` doesn't evaluate to something that's at least `202000`, see https://godbolt.org/z/5s1j1n17e

Comment: @NathanPierson Fair enough I didn't check that and should have

Comment: @fabian it's possible to define `__cplusplus` to any value you want with the `-D` option, but you'll get a compiler warning when you do so.

Comment: Instead of relying on `__cplusplus` value, I would recommend starting from C++20 to check [feature test macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test).

Comment: "*I have to make the test pass by changing the build value of my local C++ version, I just don't know how.*" Well, you can't. You cannot *make* a compiler set that value to a value that it does not want to set it to.

Answer (score 0):

Before a future standard version is standardized, the actual value for the future version is not known.  Compilers that "support" the new version before standardization will have to pick a value larger than the old one but won't have the "standard" value.

What you can do, though, is check if `__cplusplus` is greater than the version of the previous standard.  For instance, `__cplusplus` in C++17 has the value `201703`, so the value [GCC 10.3 returns of `201709`](https://godbolt.org/z/44jGbfWE8) is greater than that, so you "know" that you have a version that is newer than C++17.

Comment: But what if that test is set fixed? In my case it's for a university assignment, I can't edit or ignore this line at all

Comment: @TheBest_Kappa If you can't change the code then you need to update your compiler to a version that has the correct standard version.  GCC 11 does report the correct value for C++20: https://godbolt.org/z/rddWeWec3

Answer (score 0):

The `__cplusplus` is meant to provide an answer to the following question: "what version of C++ does this implementation claim to support?" This is a very broad question, particular in terms of the exact definition of "support".

GCC 10.3 does not feel that its support of C++20 is sufficient to meet some definition of "support". Therefore, it does not claim to "support" C++20, even if that's the version you asked for.

This is not something you get to change. There is no compiler option to force GCC to answer the question in a different way.

If you cannot upgrade GCC to a version that is willing to claim "support" for C++20, and you cannot remove or alter the change, then you're out of luck.